# Node.js - How to create a unique id with mongoose db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with Twitter authentication and want to store the twitter id as unique key in mongodb. However i see multiple entries with the same id. Here's my schema and code

Schema:

```
var TwitterSchema = new Schema({
    accessToken: String,
    accessTokenSecret: String,
    name: String,
    twitterId: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true, sparse: true } }
});
```

Code:

```
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/twd')
        mongoose.model('Post', TwitterSchema);    
        var Post = mongoose.model('Post');

        var post = new Post();
        post.accessToken = accessToken
        post.accessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret
        post.name = twitterUserData.name
        post.twitterId = twitterUserData.id

        post.save(function(err){
            if (err){
                throw err;
                promise.fail(err);
             }
            console.log('saved');
            mongoose.disconnect();
        });

        promise.fulfill(post);
```

DB shell output

```
> db.posts.find();
{ "twitterId" : "21475255", "name" : "MMMK", "accessTokenSecret" : "ZYhiXMWfXvSr1aaCB93hgU243j8aapP0ALdSFlWEE", "accessToken" : "22475255-9YvKMceUInUIxcEtKAK0oMRRG2ZZxn5c52vnwPw", "_id" : ObjectId("4feddf6155203990e000001") }
{ "twitterId" : "21475255", "name" : "MMMK, "accessTokenSecret" : "ZYhiXMWfXvSr1aaCB93hgU2438aapP0ALdSFlWEE", "accessToken" : "22475255-9YvKMceUInUIxcEtKAK0oMRRG2ZZxn5c52vnwPw", "_id" : ObjectId("4feddf7b5905a1a10e000001") }
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `db.posts.getIndexes();`?  That would confirm whether the expected unique index actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is either the index isn't being created in MongoDB, or the index with the same name already exits. If it already exists, mongoose will use `ensureIndex` to create it, but that won't override/redefine it if it already exists. Use the mongo js shell to see if it exists, then try dropping it, restarting mongod, and running your node.js code again.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CreationOptions

Comment: I tried restarting mongodb but didn't work. Not sure where's the problem. Added output from db shell

Comment: Have you also tried dropping the existing index on `twitterId` like Peter suggested to ensure it's created as you have it currently defined?

Comment: A new unique index will not be created if there are already duplicates in the collection.  You can fix this (with extreme caution: DELETES data which is duplicate or null) using [dropDups:true](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-dropDups%3Atrue).